# Colision проблема с размером спрайта и срабатыванием скрипта

Tags: c#

Хочу написать скрипт для Unity .При столкновении 2 спрайта меняют 
цвет.Нашел код в интернете и по его примеру уже писал скрипт.Напоролся на 
несколько ошибок и ни как не могу исправить .Первая не могу задать 
размеры.Вторая вытекает из первой я так думаю, при столкновении не меняют 
 цвет.

```
{
public GameObject GoodTexture;
public GameObject EvilTexture;
private Vector2 _evilSpritePosition;
private Vector2 _goodSpritePosition;
private Point _goodSpriteSize;
private Point _evilSpriteSize;
SpriteRenderer _spritegoodTexture;
SpriteRenderer _spriteevilTexture;
public void Start()
{
    GoodTexture.transform.position = new Vector2(-4, 0);
    EvilTexture.transform.position = new Vector2(-4, 0);
    _evilSpritePosition = GoodTexture.transform.position;
    _goodSpritePosition = EvilTexture.transform.position;
    _spritegoodTexture = GoodTexture.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    _spriteevilTexture = EvilTexture.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
}
public bool Collide()

{
    Point _goodSpriteSize = new Point(GoodTexture.Width, GoodTexture.Height);
    Point _evilSpriteSize = new Point(EvilTexture.Width, EvilTexture.Height);
// GameObject" не содержит определения "Width", и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения "Width", принимающий тип "GameObject"

    Rectangle goodSpriteRect = new Rectangle((int)_goodSpritePosition.x,
        (int)_goodSpritePosition.y, _goodSpriteSize.X, _goodSpriteSize.Y);
    Rectangle evilSpriteRect = new Rectangle((int)_evilSpritePosition.x,
   (int)_evilSpritePosition.y, _evilSpriteSize.X, _evilSpriteSize.Y);

    return goodSpriteRect.IntersectsWith(evilSpriteRect);
}
public  void Update()

{
    {
        GoodTexture.transform.Translate(new Vector2(1, 0) * Time.deltaTime);
        EvilTexture.transform.Translate(new Vector2(-1, 0) * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    {
        if (Collide())
            _spritegoodTexture.color = UnityEngine.Color.red;

        else
            _spritegoodTexture.color = UnityEngine.Color.blue;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пришлось немного переделать скрипт вот рабочий вариант. Проблемы были в чётком определении координат.

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Drawing;

    public class Colision : MonoBehaviour
    {
//here  obj from scene
public GameObject GoodObject, EvilObject;
private float _g2,_g1;
private float _e2, _e1;
private Vector2 _goodObjectPosition, _evilObjectPosition;
public RectTransform GoodObjectTexture, EvilObjectTexture;
private SpriteRenderer _spriteGoodTexture, _spriteEvilTexture;
private Point _goodRectSize, _evilRectSize;

public void Start() 
{
    //add my sprites/textures option "Color change"
    _spriteGoodTexture = GoodObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    _spriteEvilTexture = EvilObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

    _goodRectSize = new Point((int)GoodObjectTexture.rect.height, (int)GoodObjectTexture.rect.width);
    _evilRectSize = new Point((int)EvilObjectTexture.rect.height, (int)EvilObjectTexture.rect.width);


}
public void Update()

{

    _g1 = (float)GoodObject.transform.position.x;
    _g2 = (float) GoodObject.transform.position.y;

    _e1 = (float)EvilObject.transform.position.x;
    _e2 = (float)EvilObject.transform.position.y;

    RectangleF goodSpriteRect = new RectangleF(_g1,
        _g2, (float)_goodRectSize.X, (float)_goodRectSize.Y);
    RectangleF evilSpriteRect = new RectangleF(_e1,
        _e2, (float)_evilRectSize.X, (float)_evilRectSize.Y);


    if (goodSpriteRect.IntersectsWith(evilSpriteRect))
    {
        _spriteGoodTexture.color = UnityEngine.Color.red; 
        _spriteEvilTexture.color = UnityEngine.Color.red;
    }
    else
    {
     _spriteEvilTexture.color = UnityEngine.Color.blue;
      _spriteGoodTexture.color = UnityEngine.Color.blue;   
    }
}
```

}